# In a JUnit test, is there a way I can ensure that all assertions have been executed?

Tags: java, junit, lambda, java-8, junit4

I have a `Producer` and a `Consumer`.  `Producer` writes messages synchronously. The consumer is a thread that polls for messages every second.

I have a test like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldConsumeMessageWhenMessageIsProduced() {
    final Message expectedMessage = new Message("test");
    //consumer will poll every 1 second for a message
    consumer.poll((actualMessage) -> {assertThat(actualMessage), is(expectedMessage));
    producer.sendSynchronously(expectedMessage);
    Thread.sleep(3000);      
}
```

This test works. However, there is no way for me to ensure that the assertion was actually invoked.

I realize that I could use Mockito, but I also realize that this is more of an integration test than a unit test.  But is there anyway in JUnit to ensure that all the assertions have been executed?

Please note since the assertion is in a lambda, I cannot increment a variable or set a flag.

Comment: It's been a while, but if I remember correctly - It's best practice to only have one assertion per test.  You might want to try and re-work the tests so that you are only testing one thing at a time.  If you're expecting a collection to be returned, then compare that collection to a test collection, not the individual members of the collection.

Comment: You can create a List with single Integer element, and use it as counter. Since the List will be effectively final, you can use it inside lambda.

Comment: You probably could use Mockito to mock the "poll"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want your test to wait until the assertion is triggered, probably with a time out. A [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) could do the job:

```
@Test
public void shouldConsumeMessageWhenMessageIsProduced() {
    final Message expectedMessage = new Message("test");

    CountDownLatch messageReceived = new CountDownLatch(1);

    //consumer will poll every 1 second for a message
    consumer.poll(actualMessage -> {
      assertThat(actualMessage, is(expectedMessage));
      messageReceived.countDown();
    }

    producer.sendSynchronously(expectedMessage);

    //wait until the message is received, but not more than one second
    //await returns false if it reaches the timeout
    assertTrue(messageReceived.await(1, SECONDS));
}
```

If you expect the assertion in the consumer to be triggered n times, you can change the initial count of the latch: `CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(n);`.

Answer (score 3):

I would make use either `AtomicBoolean` or `MutableBoolean` from your lambda expression depending on your preference. See the following code for an example:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import org.apache.commons.lang.mutable.MutableBoolean;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AssertionLambdaTest {
    @Test
    public void assertExecutedWithAtomicBoolean() {
        AtomicBoolean myBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        doStuff(() -> {
            assertTrue(true);
            myBoolean.set(true);
        });
        assertTrue(myBoolean.get());
    }

    @Test
    public void assertExecutedWithMutableBoolean() {
        MutableBoolean myBoolean = new MutableBoolean(false);
        doStuff(() -> {
            assertTrue(true);
            myBoolean.setValue(true);
        });
        assertTrue(myBoolean.booleanValue());
    }

    private void doStuff(Runnable runner) {
        runner.run();
    }
}
```

Edit: I just realized that your question said "*all assertions*". As such, you could equivalently use [Apache's `MutableInt` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html) or [Java's `AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) in the same way, just incrementing until the correct number has been reached.